# Mobile menu dropdown issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my website: http://lowandheavy.com
The problem is that when website opens in mobile the 2nd menu with name "women" not working like menu "men".

It opens the dropdown but redirecting immediately to the submenu 3. Here is the code:

```
<ul class="nav-menu navigation-tier navigation-tier-primary" data-navigation-tier-primary>

     <li class="has-slide-out header-navigation-item navigation-item-primary">
      <a class="navigation-link-primary" href="/" >Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown has-slide-out header-navigation-item navigation-item-primary">
    <a class="dropbtn navigation-link-primary" href="#">Men</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="/men/tanks/">Tanks </a>
        <a href="/men/tshirts">T-shirts</a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown has-slide-out header-navigation-item navigation-item-primary">
    <a class="dropbtn navigation-link-primary" href="#">Women</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content"> 
        <a href="/women/leggings/">Leggings</a>
        <a href="/women/tanks">Tanks</a>
        <a href="/women/tshirts">T-shirts</a>
        <a href="/women/tshirts/v-neck/">V-Neck</a>
        <a href="/women/unisex-tees/">Unisex Tees</a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="has-slide-out header-navigation-item navigation-item-primary">
      <a class="navigation-link-primary" href="/hats/" >Hats</a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-slide-out header-navigation-item navigation-item-primary">
      <a class="navigation-link-primary" href="/about/" >About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-slide-out header-navigation-item navigation-item-primary">
      <a class="navigation-link-primary" href="/contact-us/" >Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-slide-out header-navigation-item navigation-item-primary">
      <a class="navigation-link-primary" href="/news-feed/" >News</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

Comment: what's the issue? I didn't find any

Comment: @Nirali first open the website into the mobile, then click on toggle you will see the menus list after that when you click on the menu name Men then same time click on menu name women you will find the issue its not staying its redirecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Lets DO the same on click

/***Add css in file***/

.dropdown.active .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/***Add Jquery in file***/

$('.navigation-link-primary').click(function(e){
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on the menu name Men then same time click on menu name women you are facing issue that its not staying its redirecting

It is not the issue
It is happening because when you click on menu "Men" It opens a submenu of Men. then same time clicking on woman submenu of woman open and submenu of "Men" close so gap reduce between Men and Woman in directly you clicked upon one of the submenu of "Woman" (Maybe 2nd or 3rd submenu) not clicked upon the "Woman" menu and you are getting redirected.

Check below snippet

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
     <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="btn-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1" aria-expanded="false">Link 2 (toggle)</a>
   <ul class="nav collapse" id="submenu1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-1">
    <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2.3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
    <li><a href="#" id="btn-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu2" aria-expanded="false">Link 3 (toggle)</a>
   <ul class="nav collapse" id="submenu2" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-1">
    <li><a href="#">Link 3.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3.3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

If you are directly open "woman" menu then you will not see your issue because at that time Submenu of "Men" menu is not open

Comment: I am looking for solutions to solve this I want to how make it stay there both even clicking same time

Comment: If one submenu is already is open and uou click on other menu that keep open above submenu don't close. It will work

Comment: yes i just want to stay both menu open just not want this dirty redirection

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj check my answer i added snippet

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.dropbtn.navigation-link-primary').click(function(e){
   if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
           $("a.dropbtn.navigation-link-primary").removeClass('active');
        }
        else {
           $(this).addClass('active');
        }
 });
```

```css
@media(max-width:850px) {
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: none !important;
}
body.home .main-header-menu .header-navigation-item a {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
a.dropbtn.navigation-link-primary.active+div {
    display: block !important;
}
}
```